# Problems with Lists and ImmutableLists

Tags: java, list, jmonkeyengine

So I have this weird error in my program (The last error before there is supposedly no more) that I cannot solve no matter what I do. I am using jMonkey Engine 3 (jme3) and this is the piece of code with the error:

```
public List<Element> getTerrainElements() {
    return ImmutableList.builder().addAll(this.elements).build();
  }
```

and the error is this:

```
incompatible types
required: List<Element>
found:    ImmutableList<Object>
```

No matter what I try on this bit of code I always get an error and I want to knnow how to get rid of the error so I can start to debug my program. If any more information is needed to answer my question, just ask and I will be glad to tell you anything I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do

```
return ImmutableList.<Element>builder().addAll(this.elements).build();
```

instead.

`ImmutableList.builder()` is not able to infer the generic type, so you need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: So far the error is not showing up so I will debug really quickly and ill be back but so far this worked! :D

Comment: Answer given by @lae is correct but I would like to share my experience.I generally use the ImmutableList.copyOf() static factory method as it is a nice clean generic factory method